What is the way to send structured log fields with log4j?
With slf4j I can do as follows:
logger.atInfo()
  .setMessage("My message")
  .addKeyValue("foo", "bar")
  .addKeyValue("code", 42)
  .log()

Which, when used with Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry Exporter and Appender for Logback, produces entries in traces App Insight tables like this:

How to achieve the same result with log4j logging interface? I could not find a method overload accepting extra attributes.

log4j2 provides MapMessage for structured data. Have you checked that out? https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#structured-logging

Here is the reference that allows you to send structured log fields with Log4j, similar to how you would with SLF4J and Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry Exporter.


How to achieve the same result with log4j logging interface? I could not find a method overload accepting extra attributes.


ThreadContext in Log4j allows you to add contextual data (like key-value pairs), which will be included with every log message. This is similar to SLF4J's MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) and is supported by most layouts, including the JsonLayout and PatternLayout.

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Logtest {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Logtest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Add extra attributes using ThreadContext (similar to SLF4J MDC)
        ThreadContext.put("Role", "Admin");
        ThreadContext.put("Location", "USA");
        ThreadContext.put("SessionId", "abc-123"):

        // Log the message
        logger.info("My message");

        // Clear the context when done
        ThreadContext.clearAll();
    }
}


Log4j’s MapMessage class allows you to create structured logs with key-value pairs, which are similar to SLF4J’s addKeyValue() method.

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MapMessage;

public class Logtest {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Logtest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a structured log message using MapMessage
        MapMessage logEntry = new MapMessage();
        logEntry.put("foo", "bar");
        logEntry.put("code", "42");

        // Log the structured message
        logger.info(logEntry);
    }
}

With this above configuration, both the ThreadContext and MapMessage examples will output logs in a structured JSON format.
{
  "timeMillis": 1695408341456,
  "thread": "main",
  "level": "INFO",
  "loggerName": "LogExample",
  "message": "This is a structured log message",
  "contextMap": {
    "Role": "Admin",
    "Location": "USA",
    "SessionId": "abc-123"
  }
}


Log Traces (extra attributes added):



Thank you for the examples. I read about MapMessage, but could not figure out how to pass the main message itself. After some experimenting, it's message key. Also, for the Appender class, it is important to enable captureMapMessageAttributes and captureContextDataAttributes configuration settings otherwise they will be ignored.
